# IoT Edge Offline capabilities

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are using IoT Edge Offline functionality and would like to understand the current mechanism to upload offline data to cloud :

- The frequency at which offline data is uploaded to cloud
- Data transfer rate
- When device comes online – priority of data transfer (like offline
  data will have more priority than online data etc.)

Any additional information around above questions will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :) Do ensure better answers to your questions please make sure to follow the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show us also, what your found during your research.

Answer (score 0):

> The frequency at which offline data is uploaded to cloud

I *guess* you mean "how often does Edge Hub check if connectivity is restored. If that is your question, I don't have the accurate answer, but from my experience, Edge Hub is back online after 30-60sec after connectivity is restored. Once it is back online, it automatically starts to upload stored/queued data to the cloud.

> Data transfer rate

That mostly depends on your network bandwidth and the size of your messages. You will need to test this in your specific setup.

> When device comes online – priority of data transfer (like offline data will have more priority than online data etc.)

First in, first out. So the data that has been queued earlier (when the device was offline), will be uploaded first:

> Once the connection with IoT Hub is restored, the IoT Edge device syncs again. Locally stored messages are delivered in the same order in which they were stored.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities#how-it-works